# Where do we get the SMTP Authentication information?

Tags: form

We are trying to get Office 365 working with a Craft website.  How do we know what the host name and port number is.  Plus, under SMTP authentication setting is asking for a username & password, where do I find this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-settings-for-POP-and-IMAP-access-for-Office-365-for-business-or-Microsoft-Exchange-accounts-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c), the Office 365 SMTP server is `smtp.office365.com` using port 587 and TLS encryption. Your username and password you'd get from your hosting provider as it's not Craft-specific information.

Comment: Didn't really warrant a new answer, so I just butchered yours. :)

Comment: Is that the same thing as the login information for Go Daddy (Host)